# ckeditor error: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I m getting an error "Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined" when there is no text entered in CK-Editor. If there is some text entered in the editor then it works fine.. I don't understand why is this happening..
M using following code for fetching the entered data in the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.form_description.getData();
```

Please suggest something..

Comment: can you show your complete code. are you fetching it on which event ?

Comment: Actually i m using WP-editor in Wordpress. When CK-editor Plugin is activated then it overrides wp-editor. So that's why i checked a condition that if ck-editor is activated then the above code will work.. For Displaying editor i m simply using :  wp_editor("", $id = "form_description",$name = "form_description", $media_buttons = true, $tab_index = 1);

Comment: are you trying to fetch on keyup event? when is this line called `CKEDITOR.instances.form_description.getData();`

Comment: No.. its called when i submit the form..

Comment: let me try to replicate it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear Simranjeet Kaur In The Code add checks for in ckeditor add check or not or you can try try catck block for resolve this error. this type error come because instance not created when you type text then create instance then dont getting any error

code like below

> try
>   {
>       CKEDITOR.instances.form_description.getData(); } catch (ex) {
>   }

Comment: Thanks, it works and not giving me any error when there is no text in the editor.. but m unfamiliar with the try-catch condition.. could you please tell me how i will get text in case there is data in the editor and do not get error in case there is no data in the editor..